# Substract a date in Multi array

Tags: php

I'm new to php ;)
I need to substract two date, stocked in a multidimensionnal array :

```
  45 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '2016-01-17 17:08:48' (length=19)
      'recall' => string '0' (length=1)
  46 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '2016-01-17 17:12:43' (length=19)
      'recall' => string '5' (length=1)
  47 => 
    array (size=2)
      'date' => string '2016-01-17 17:22:46' (length=19)
      'recall' => string '5' (length=1)
```

I need to Have foreach, date - recall, but i don't understand wich syntax i need to use.. Someone can help the newbie ?

Of Course i tried ;)

```
$date_array = array();
$date = array();

foreach ( $results as $f ) {
    $date_array['date'] = $f['date_to'];
    $date_array['recall'] = $f['recall'];
    $date[] = $date_array;
}

foreach ($date as $d ) {
    $d = date_sub($date['date'],$date['recall']);
    $date[] = $d;
}
var_dump($date);
```

I think i missunderstand how to use [datetime.sub](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.sub.php)

I want to obtain an array similar to :

```
  45 => 
    array (size=1)
      'date' => string '2016-01-12 17:08:48' (length=19)
  46 => 
    array (size=1)
      'date' => string '2016-01-12 17:12:43' (length=19)
  ...
```

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please be more precise. Do you want to iterate through the inner arrays? What excactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP date_sub subtracts a period of time from a date. So for example, to get 10 days before a given date.
Subtracting a date from another date suggests you want to know the period of time in between those two dates. To do that you can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). What this does is converts your date in to a number, in seconds. You can then subtract one from another using normal subtraction.

So it would look something like this:

```
foreach ($date as $d ) {
    $d = strtotime($date['date']) - strtotime($date['recall']);
    // Now $d is the number of seconds between recall and date
}
```

The result is the number of seconds between the two dates - so you can divide it by 60 to get the number of minutes, etc.